# How to replace multiple whitespaces without modifying newline characters?

Tags: c#, regex

So as title says I have a huge problem with replacing multiple whitespaces and \t with single whitespace-symbol. For example, I have following string:

> ```
>    &!(0-=\+_)(         ^(there goes '\n')
>    &!(0-=\+_)(
> ```

As you can see, my string consists of both \t and \s symbols. I have already tried this method:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t+", " ");
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
```

But at the end I'm receiving simple string, without newline characters. So....if there are any ways to ignore newline characters? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t+", " ");
line = Regex.Replace(line, @" +", " ");
```

It translates the string `"a b c\t\t\t\nd e      f"` to `a b c \nd e f`

For an explanation see for example: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html :

`The \s (lowercase s) matches a whitespace (blank, tab \t, form-feed \f and newline \r or \n).`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please explain why this is impossible with "\s+"?

Answer (score 0):

```
[ ]+
```

Try this.It works for me.See demo.Replace by `space`.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/12

`\s=[\r\n\t\f ]`

it includes `newline`.so it wont work.